# Finding all values such that column vector is a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Question:

For which values(s) of $ \ a$ is the column $ \ c = \begin{bmatrix} a\\a^2\\0\\a+1\end{bmatrix}$ a linear combination of the columns of,

$ \ x = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\ y = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $ \ z= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

My attempt:

$ \ c = \begin{bmatrix} a\\a^2\\0\\a+1\end{bmatrix} = \ r\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + s \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $

We know its a linear combination $\iff $   $ \ r+s = a, r+t = a^2, r-s = 0, r+t = a+1$  . I am not sure how to find all values of $ \ a$ now.

Comment: Have you tried solving your equations for $a$?

Comment: I get $ \ a= 2r, a = -2t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
Using your four obtained equations, you know that $r=s$ and so $2r=a.$ You then have $t=a^2-\frac{a}{2}.$ Inserting all that into the last equation, you get 
$$\cancel{\frac{a}{2}}+a^2-\cancel{\frac{a}{2}}=a+1,$$
the solutions of which are $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

Comment: Careful, that should be $t = a^2 - \frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Whoops, my bad, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

A necessary condition is:

$$a^2 = r+t = a+1 \implies a = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Then you have $2r = a \implies r = s = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$ so in that case the rows are indeed linearly dependent.

Thus, the rows are linearly dependent iff $a = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$